# Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined

Tags: angular-cli

I have installed Angular/cli and then try to run command ng serve then below error is throwing. I have tried lot of thing like uninstall angular/cli, npm cache clean, etc

> Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be
>   determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.
>
> Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli
>   and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_modules and
>   package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm install again.

Comment: did you get it working till now ?

Comment: Yeah I tried solution with versions change then it is worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

This may be a problem in not implicitly running devDependencies.

Try running them implicitly with the command below.

```
npm install --dev
```

Comment: Ok will check this one.

Comment: install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Generic way out to escape this issue

1. Create a new project

   ng new angular-seed
2. Copy all the default dependencies and dev-dependenices from package.json to your current project in use (angular, typescript, etc...)

[image]

3. Then remove node_modules and run install npm packages of your current project, or whatever method you use to reubild

   rm -fr node_modules
   npm install

note: if this doesn't get you the latest version, then you may have global tools installed in roaming data
(in window explored browser type `%appdata%`, and navigate to npm to observe)

Comment: I find this generic method useful for solving many Angular problems, including problems with upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Open the command prompt in your project folder.

#### 2. Run the command.

```
 npm install --only=dev
```

Answer (score 2):

**By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies.** With the --production flag, npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.
either 
we can go

**First Way**

for **editing the** **dependency part in package.json** by adding it with relevant version

```
    "dependencies": {
    /*existing part */

     "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
    }
```

**Second Way**

To install dev dependencies, **npm --production=false install** will work even with NODE_ENV=production.

Or you can run **NODE_ENV=development npm install**

for more details 
[click to know more](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8407)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of deployment, it is a good idea to add a `preinstall` script to address these gaps in dependencies:

```
"preinstall": "npm install @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, for prevent, update angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Second, also the run "npm install", you must install dev dependencies

```
npm install --dev
```

verify dependencies are without error

```
ng --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that your "@angular/compiler" in your dependencies is compatible with angular/cli version.

For example :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
```

is compatible with :

```
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
```

Comment: i had the same issue. i made sure compiler and compiler-cli are in the same version, but issue still exists.

Comment: Yes I have the DevDependencies like below

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command

```
npm --production=false install
```

in your terminal.
Also note that you should be in your project folder while executing this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the real problem is with npm.

If its downloading as `--legacy-bundling=true` **(Which is by default)** then you will have this issue. If you see node_modules folder all the dependent modules would be nested.

When you run `npm install` command you should set `--legacy-bundling=false`

```
npm install --legacy-bundling=false
```

Now if you see node_modules folder no any module would be nested. And everything will work.

You can set npm default behaviour using following command, then you will not have to set every time.

```
npm set --legacy-bundling=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when I was installing npm dependencies on Jenkins.  I had @angular/compiler-cli in devDependencies and typescript in dependencies and `NODE_ENV=production` in the environment.

I tried `NODE_ENV=development npm install` and it worked for me.

For more details see this : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8407

Answer (score 0):

> Also check these dependencies `package.json`:

```
...
"@angular/cli": "x.x.x",
"@angular/compiler": "^y.y.y",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^z.z.z",
"typescript": "^t.t.t"
...
```