# Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined in the Angular Js

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

> *Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined. The most common reason for this is a broken npm install.*
>   *Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and run npm install again.*

for more details please have a look at the attachment
[image]

I have added @angular/cli, @angular/compilet-cli and typescripts as displayed in the image.

I have updated related version and ran npm i to reinstall all the packages , Restarted the VS code. But the same error is displayed.

I have tried answers of the [Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185611/versions-of-angular-compiler-cli-and-typescript-could-not-be-determined).  But no luck.

Seeking for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Versions of @angular/compiler-cli and typescript could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185611/versions-of-angular-compiler-cli-and-typescript-could-not-be-determined)

Comment: I have tried all the options of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185611/versions-of-angular-compiler-cli-and-typescript-could-not-be-determined , But issue is not resovled.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve problem:

- delete node_modules folder
- run npm install --only=dev --legacy-bundling=false
- run npm start

Comment: I have tried that too, But no luck !!

All the dependencies are installed under node_Modules then too i am facing such error. And i have also mentioned the cli and typeScripts in the Devdependenices.

Comment: Now try with-- >  npm install --only=dev --legacy-bundling=false

Comment: only run npm start

Comment: jsut try using ng serve OR npm start